# When you and someone else often joke together

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning

I was out with a friend. A stranger heard the way we talked with each other. The stranger became offended at some of the vulgar language we used and I found him a bit uneasy and uncomfortable; so I decided to tell him in English:

- > Don't worry, **he and I have jokes together.**

**Connotation:** we often joke with each other.

I was wondering if the bold part above sounds correct to you. If not, then what is the naturally idiomatic way to express this matter?

Comment: You might be looking for "it's an inside joke" which is used to express the idea that it's a "running" or "ongoing" joke between the two of you.  Be aware that in the English-speaking realm, if you used racist language you'll be marked as racist, and that's that. Nobody cares if it was a joke, or, a private ongoing joke.

Comment: I think the point @Fattie is trying to make is this: If you use offensive language (be it vulgar, racist, sexist, etc.), it doesn't really matter if you are only joking with your friend or not – people might still be offended.

Answer (score 3):

I think  the connotation would be :

> **we crack jokes at  each other**

I here with attach a linkto make things clear

https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/crack-a-joke

Comment: Thank you @JVL, just one more question. If my Japanese friend became offended, what he could say me from among my following made-up sentences: 1. "Did I ever **joke with you**?" --- 2. "Did I ever **joke with you in this sense**?" --- 3. "Did I ever **crack jokes at you**?" --- 4. "Did I ever **crack such jokes at you**?" Please let me know what is the most natural way to say this in English?

Comment: Also, I have almost always used this idiom "crack a joke at someone", "when someone wants to tell a joke" as it is clear in your shared link. I wonder if it has an alternate meaning too.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98986/discussion-between-a-friend-and-jvl).

Answer (score 3):

As a native English speaker, "don't worry, he and I have jokes together" does not necessarily seem grammatically incorrect, however it does not sound natural. It also does not convey the message that I think you are trying to say. It would be better to say something along the lines of:

- Don't worry, we always joke with each other like this.
- Don't worry, we have quite a brutal way of joking with each other.
- Don't worry, we have our own way of joking with each other.
- Don't worry, we both know we are just joking.
- Don't worry, we have some pretty harsh ways of joking / inside jokes.

Because to me 'we always have jokes with each other' seems like you are trying to say 'we always have a good time when we are together'.

Comment: Decent suggestions, although "quite a brutal way" sounds a bit stilted in this context.